# Quickly filter an object by keys

Tags: javascript, performance

I am trying to optimize an object filter function. Given an array of keys, I need to filter an object. I feel that creating a new object each time may degrade performance. Is there a way to mock the `Array.prototype.filter` function for objects?

```js
function main() {
    var Types = {
        INTEGER:   { value: 'int'    },
        CHARACTER: { value: 'char'   },
        FLOAT:     { value: 'float'  },
        DOUBLE :   { value: 'double' },
        STRING:    { value: 'str'    },
        BOOLEAN:   { value: 'bool'   }
    };
    
    var Numbers = filterByKeys(Types, [ 'INTEGER', 'FLOAT', 'DOUBLE' ]);
    
    console.log(Numbers);
};

function listToSet(list) {
    var _set = {};
    if (Ext.isArray(list)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            _set[list[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    return _set;
};

function filterByKeys(obj, keep) {
    var result = {},
        unfiltered = keep === undefined,
        keys = listToSet(keep);
    if (Ext.isObject(obj)) {
        Ext.Array.each(Object.keys(obj), function(key) {
            if (unfiltered ||  (!unfiltered && keys[key])) {
                result[key] = obj[key];
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
};

Ext.onReady(function () {
    main();
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-all.js"></script>
```

#### Without ExtJS Dependency

```js
function main() {
    var Types = {
        INTEGER:   { value: 'int'    },
        CHARACTER: { value: 'char'   },
        FLOAT:     { value: 'float'  },
        DOUBLE :   { value: 'double' },
        STRING:    { value: 'str'    },
        BOOLEAN:   { value: 'bool'   }
    };
    
    var Numbers = filterByKeys(Types, [ 'INTEGER', 'FLOAT', 'DOUBLE' ]);
    
    console.log(Numbers);
};

function listToSet(list) {
    var _set = {};
    if (isArr(list)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            _set[list[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    return _set;
};

function filterByKeys(obj, keep) {
    var result = {},
        unfiltered = keep === undefined,
        keys = listToSet(keep);
    if (isObj(obj)) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (unfiltered ||  (!unfiltered && keys[key])) {
                result[key] = obj[key];
            }
        };
    }
    return result;
};

var tObj='[object Object]',tArr='[object Array]',str=Object.prototype.toString;
var isArr='isArray'in Array?Array.isArray:function(v){return str.call(v)===tArr};
var isObj=str.call(null)===tObj?function(v){return v!==null&&v!==void 0&&str.call(v)===tObj&&v.ownerDocument===void 0}:function(v){return str.call(v)===tObj
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    main();
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you already have [lodash](https://lodash.com) in your toolkit, you can use [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) for this task.

Answer (score 14):

1. Use `var myKeys = Object.keys(myObject)` to get the keys.
2. Check if a `myString` exist in the array `myKeys` using native

   ```
   var matchingKey = myKeys.indexOf(myString) !== -1
   ```

   **Processing an array?** Use this:

   ```
   var matchingKeys = myKeys.filter(function(key){ return key.indexOf(myString) !== -1 });
   ```
3. Get the value using `myObject[matchingKey]`.

   **Processing an array?** Use this:

   ```
   var matchingValues = matchingKeys .map(function(key){ return myObject[key] });
   ```
4. No need to check array-boundaries or sizes. It's 100% boundary-safe.

Comment: Step 2. Can be simplified `var matchingKey = myKeys.includes(myString)` and for array Processing `var matchingKeys = myKeys.filter((key) => key.includes(myString));`

Answer (score 4):

I think that the more important questions you need to be asking yourself wrt your code are:

1. What am I *really* trying to accomplish? (Answering this question will ultimately resolve your uncertainty related to whether you need to create a new object every time or, maybe, modify in place etc.)
2. Am I using the right *data-structure* for the task? Look, you've built your data-structure from hash-tables, each with a single key! Not only that, the same key repeats in every such hash-table! What would you lose if you used just the value from that hash-table instead of the entire hash-table?
3. This has become a mantra, but it is as true as ever: *Make It Work, Make It Right, Make It Fast*. Do not optimize unless the profiler tells you to. And most certainly not before you are absolutely confident that you made it right.

As an example of how your data-structure could've been made different such as to allow you to make filtering more straightforward:

```
var types = {
    'integer':   'int', 
    'character': 'char',
    'float':     'float',
    'double':    'double',
    'string':    'str', 
    'boolean':   'bool'
};

function filterTypes(accepted) {
    var result = {};
    for (var type in types)
        if (accepted.indexOf(type) > -1) 
            result[type] = types[type];
    return result;
}
// filterTypes(['integer', 'float', 'double']);
// { integer: 'int',
//   float: 'float',
//   double: 'double' }
```

And this is all there is to it.  I would also question the purpose of these types in JavaScript, but I assumed they aren't to be implemented in JavaScript, just some kind of labels for some other programming language.

Note, additionally, that since the `types` hash-table is relatively small, there is no point of copying the keys to check against into another hash-table (to achieve faster lookup instead of `indexOf`). With this number of types `indexOf` will most likely outperform hash-table lookup, even more importantly. It offers a simpler solution, which works with acceptable speed.

Comment: But in nowadays (2019!)... No modern EC6 filter for objects?

Comment: @PeterKrauss I think, you meant ES6, and... I don't have the standard handy, but, from looking at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object there isn't a method for filtering object fields, unless I'm blind. But, my guess is that JS standardization committee cannot still decide whether `{}` is just a hash-table, or is it more like a class instance in other languages. Every now and then the standard shifts from one perspective to another, but it's what prevents them from treating it just like a hash-table, and adding that kind of functionality

Answer (score 3):

1. `unfiltered ||  (!unfiltered && keys[key])` is redundant you can just do `unfiltered || keys[key]`
2. You will run into false positives for any property set on `Object.prototype` such as `"toString"` or `"valueOf"` (for instance consider `{valueOf: 1}`)
3. `keys[key]` is not a sufficent as it will miss any falsey value (NaN, null, false, 0, "", etc). You should use either the `in` operation or `hasOwnProperty`
4. This can be done considerably faster (and more accurately) by iterating the `keep` array instead of the properties on `obj` (lets you get around a `Object.keys` call)

---

This is how I would go about it

```
// Avoid issues with `{hasOwnProperty: 5}`
var hasOwnProperty = ({}).hasOwnProperty;
function filterByKeys(obj, keep) {
    if (!(Ext.isObject(obj) && keep)) {
        return Ext.clone(obj);
    }

    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = keep.length; i < len; i++) {
        var key = keep[i];
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            result[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```